# how to interpret postgres timezon

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I am working on resolving a timezone issue and just want to understand how to interpret the timezone if I have got it right

> 2018-01-04 22:31:23.1+00

date time.1+00 ..any simple explanation on how can I know which time zone is this ?

Comment: +00 is GMT / Zulu etc. i.e. no offset.

Comment: what does .1 refer to?

Comment: fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2018-01-04 22:31:23.1+00

Year:   2018
Month:  01     (January)
Day:    04

Hour:   22     (10pm)
Minute: 31
Second: 23.1   (.1 is one-tenth of a second)

Offset: +00    (hours East of GMT)
```

Note, you cannot determine which *time zone* this is in - only the offset from UTC/GMT applicable at that timestamp.

Since multiple time zones can use UTC+00, you don't know which of those time zones it is in.  It might just be in UTC, but it might be in `Atlantic/Reykjavik`, or `Africa/Casablanca`.  One uses UTC year round, the other switches between UTC and UTC+1.  There are others as well.

Comment: very clean. Thanks!

Comment: so how would I know this information - Atlantic/Reykjavik, or Africa/Casablanca from above timezone

Comment: You can't.  A time zone and an offset are two different things.

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL doesn't store a timestamp with timezone WITH the timezone. It converts it to UTC THEN stores it. So once you've stored it, the TZ offset is lost. It then applies a new offset based on what the client timezone is.